# Last viewed by and page count creating error

Tags: apex, error

I got this error while working on an implementation . The error is :

> Attempt to deference a null object Error is in expression
>   '{!updatecount}' in component  in page
>   last_viewed_by_pagecount: Class.LeadPageViewCounter.updatecount: line
>   29, column 1 .

Please help .

```
public class LeadPageViewCounter {

    public Lead lead ;
    public user u{get;set;}
    public decimal count;
    public LeadPageViewCounter(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
   }

public pagereference updatecount(){


   List<Lead> lead1=new List<Lead>();
   lead1=([SELECT Id, PageCount__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')]);


   /* If (lead.size()>0)
    {

    }

   else
   {
      System.debug('List is Empty');

   } */

    u=  [select name from User where id= :UserInfo.getUserId()];

        if(lead.PageCount__c==null) {
            lead.PageCount__c=1;
            lead.Last_Viewed_By__c=u.name;
            }

        else
        {
                lead.PageCount__c+=1;
                lead.Last_Viewed_by__c=u.name;
         }
   update lead;
  return null;

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that error arises in this line:

```
if(lead.PageCount__c==null)
```

The reason is that you never initialize this `lead` variable. After you created it in the first line(`public Lead lead ;`), you never assign it any value, so this variable is `null`. And when you try to call `PageCount__c` on a `null` object, you get *Attempt to deference a null object* error.

Comment: Could you please help me out to solve the error .

Comment: @JJoseph initialize this variable. Assign it a value

Comment: I did something like this but no luck yet . 1)  public Lead lead{get;set;}  2)    lead=[SELECT Id, PageCount__c FROM Lead WHERE Id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];

Comment: @JJoseph debug it, make sure that this variable is being assigned(so that it's not `null` before you try `lead.PageCount__c`

Answer (score 0):

One of the points of using a StandardController is that it does the work for you. So providing your page references the `PageCount__c` field, theStandardController will automatically query it for you. (If your page doesn't, you can use the [StandardController.addFields](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm#apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields) method to tell the theStandardController to query it.)

So your code becomes simpler:

```
public class LeadPageViewCounter {

    private Lead lead;

    public LeadPageViewCounter(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        lead = (Lead) sc.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference updateCount() {
        lead.PageCount__c = lead.PageCount__c != null ? lead.PageCount__c + 1 : 1;
        lead.Last_Viewed_By__c = UserInfo.getName();
        update lead;
        return null;
    }
}
```